# Find cosine similarity between different pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, cosine-similarity

I have three pandas dataframe, suppose group_1, group_2, group_3

```py
import pandas as pd 
   group_1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,0,1,1,1], 'B':[1,1,1,1,1]})
   group_2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1,1], 'B':[1,1,0,0,0]})
   group_3 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1,1], 'B':[0,0,0,0,0]})
```

filled dummy value, all value will be binary for above group

Now, there is another dataframe , new one

```py
new_data_frame = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1,1], 'B':[0,0,0,0,0],'mobile': ['xxxxx','yyyyy','zzzzz','wwwww','mmmmmm']})
new_data_frame.set_index('mobilenumber')

         A  B
 mobile     
 xxxxx  1   0
 yyyyy  1   0
 zzzzz  1   0
 wwwww  1   0
 mmmmmm 1   0
```

For each mobile in new_dataframe, I want to calculate mean cosine similarity(sum all score and divide by length of group dataframe), mobile number which have highest score will be assign to a particular group

So my expected output will be

```
   mobile group
   xxxxx  group_1
   yyyyy  group_1
   zzzzz  group_3
```

something like this

```
  for x in new_data_frame.to_numpy():
      score = []
      for y in group_1.to_numpy():
         a =  cosine_similarity(x,y)
         score.append(a)
      mean_score = sum(score)/len(y)
```

I have added below code , is there a better way to achive this

```
def max_group(x,group_1, group_2, group_3 ):
    x_ = x.tolist()
    val =  x_[:-1]

    group = [group_1, group_2, group_3]

    score = []
    for i in range(len(group)):
        a = cosine_similarity([val], group[i].to_numpy())
        print('<---->')
        print(a.mean())
        score.append((a.mean(), i))

    return max(score[1])
 
 new_data_frame['group'] = new_data_frame.apply(lambda x: max_group(x, group_1, group_2, group_3), axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: mobile xxxxx is similar to which group group_1 , group_2 or group_3

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh so each record in new_data_frame , will do rowwise similarity score for three different group, now I need to take mean score of each group dataframe , and assign group1 or group2 or group3 for each mobile

Comment: It would be just the best if you add a table to your question with the expected output for this given example.

Comment: @qaiser Expected output seems wrong, for all  mobiles the output should be group_3?

Comment: Added just what I want, result might be different no issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

Create a mapping of group names and values then for each group calculate the mean cosine similarity inside a dict comprehension, then create a new dataframe from the computed scores and use `idxmax` to find the name of group having max mean similarity score

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

grps = {'group_1': group_1, 'group_2': group_2, 'group_3': group_3}
scores = {k: cosine_similarity(new_data_frame, g).mean(1) for k, g in grps.items()}

pd.DataFrame(scores, index=new_data_frame.index).idxmax(1)
```

#### Result

```
mobile
xxxxx     group_3
yyyyy     group_3
zzzzz     group_3
wwwww     group_3
mmmmmm    group_3
dtype: object
```